# How to pass the msg from HttpServletResponse.sendError(status, msg) to controller?

Tags: java, spring

This is the current java (1.8) spring call stack,

1. interceptor

   `preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       response.sendError(403)
   }`
2. web.xml

   `<error-page>
      <error-code>403</error-code>
      <location>/error/forbidden</location>
   </error-page>`
3. errorController

   `@RequestMapping(value="/error/forbidden")
   public ModelAndView forbidden () {
       // display fixed message "forbidden" in the web browser
   }`

Now in interceptor, i want to send back customized messages,
`preHandle(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) {
    response.sendError(403, "my msg")
}`

Controller is changed to

```
`@RequestMapping(value="/error/forbidden")
public ModelAndView forbidden (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)`
```

The question is, when i debug into controller code, i cannot find "my msg" from response obj yet.

Q1: am i doing the right way ?

Q2: if so, where is "my msg" in the response ? if not, what's the correct way to do it pls ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sent custom message in response from preHandle method of Interceptor then try below code

```
response.setStatus(403);
response.getWriter().write("my msg");
```

Comment: very interesting, i do see "my msg" in the browser, but it's not hit errorController (step 3 in my question). Just curious, is there a way still hit the errorController, and "my msg" is in the response object ?

Comment: I don't think it will hit any Controller if exception is thrown from the preHandle method in Interceptor.

Comment: Thx, btw, can i use UTF-8 string in response.getWriter().write() ?